# What does "plaster everywhere" mean here?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

Megyn Kelly [tweeted](https://twitter.com/megynkelly/status/1325063956101259264) in response to AOC's tweet:

> What an awesome tweet for the Georgia GOP to plaster everywhere in their effort to ensure Republicans keep the Senate.
> Quote Tweet
>
> > AOC: Is anyone archiving these Trump sycophants for when they try to downplay or deny their complicity in the future? I foresee decent probability of many deleted Tweets, writings, photos in the future.

What does "plaster everywhere" mean here? What did Megyn Kelly try to say?

Thanks

Comment: At a secondary level (and, I suppose, off-topic for this site), what does Kelly ***mean**?*  ISTM that AOC’s words aren't particularly inflammatory (at least not by the standards of the past four years) and are not anything that her opposition (the Republicans) can use for political gain.  Is she reacting to the use of the word "sycophant"?  Or "complicity"?

Answer (score 13):

It is a reference to the practice of "plastering" (gluing/taping) signs, posters, notices, etc, onto walls, fences, and the like.  Years ago this would have been done for, eg, advertising a circus coming to town.  The concept has been adopted metaphorically to refer to copying computer text to Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The sense is to post the tweet everywhere:

***To [Plaster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plaster)***

> To affix to  or  place especially conspicuously or in  quantity.

(Merrian-Webster))

Comment: From wallpapering, I think.